# XML quotes within quotes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, selenium, app-config

```
 <add key="TAB_Home" value="//*[@id="kmTabContainer_HomeTab"]"/>

 <add key="TAB_Home" value='//*[@id="kmTabContainer_HomeTab"]'/>
```

The above is the code from my appConfig file. How to format quotes inside quotes in XML? When I do the first one, it says Missing Required White Space.

The second one gives me expected '>'

Comment: Are you entering XML or a C# string?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `&apos;` to represent a single quote in an attribute value delimited by single quotes.

Use `&quot;` to represent a double quote in an attribute value delimited by double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You encode them using `&quot;`:

```
<add key="TAB_Home" value="//*[@id=&quot;kmTabContainer_HomeTab&quot;]"/>
```